# Alter all tables postgres set owner

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I need a postgresql statement to run through the public schema (all tables) and update the owner. I know the manual command is `ALTER TABLE public.<table_name> OWNER TO <username>;`

However I'm not sure how to put this into a script/format which will loop through each table and update the owner?

This is for a postgres 9.6 database (it will be run on a test db).

Thanks

Comment: https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/04/postgresql-how-to-grant-access-to-users.html
maybe this link can help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Connect to the database with `psql` and run

```
SELECT format(
          'ALTER TABLE public.%I OWNER TO user_name',
          table_name
       )
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' \gexec
```

`\gexec` will execute each line of the query result as a statement.

Do upgrade.

Comment: Thank you! We plan to upgrade very soon, I realise we're on an unsupported/old version.

Comment: this only works with `psql` and not with `pgcli`

Comment: @Hritik Just like I said in my answer.